# Intel Centrino Wi-Fi high ping to router on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: network-manager, 15.10, iwlwifi, centrino

I have an Ubuntu Mate 15.10 installed.

Yesterday I noticed that the internet became slow. I've tried to ping router and the latency was something over 2000ms by 6000ms.

The temporary fix for that is:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

or toggle this by a wi-fi hotkey on the keyboard

Then it works, but after 5-10 minutes it happens again.

I've tried:

- dpkg-reconfigure the network-manager and linux-firmware
- reinstall them (linux-firmware 1.149.3 and network-manager 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.2)
- downgrade them (to linux-firmware 1.149 and network-manager 1.0.4-0ubuntu5)
- turn off the N mode (options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1)
- turn on link aggregation (options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8)
- sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 power off
- stop bluetoothd
- ping router from another device - no problem at all
- use wifi on Windows 10 on the same laptop - no problem at all

but the problem is still exists.

lspci -k:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

dmesg | grep iwl:

```
[    6.620879] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.620995] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    6.814568] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[    7.243360] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    7.243364] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[    7.243365] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[    7.243367] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
[    7.243475] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    7.373849] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[    7.399886] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   17.879340] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   17.885926] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[   17.954107] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   17.960706] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 1075.229636] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1082.851407] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[ 1082.852356] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[ 1082.872091] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[ 1082.872094] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[ 1082.872096] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[ 1082.872098] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
[ 1082.872199] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1082.889723] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[ 1082.893387] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 1082.902930] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1082.909546] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 1082.978382] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1082.985016] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 1083.047397] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1083.054072] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 1083.123509] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1083.130182] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 1097.575383] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1097.582022] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 1097.651545] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1097.658191] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 4223.416315] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4230.502905] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[ 4230.504564] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[ 4230.538883] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[ 4230.538887] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[ 4230.538890] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[ 4230.538893] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
[ 4230.539004] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4230.556700] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[ 4230.562894] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 4230.572929] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4230.579586] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 4230.655657] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4230.662286] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 4230.726274] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4230.732903] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 4230.800982] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4230.807639] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 4234.404393] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4234.411029] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 4234.481061] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4234.487798] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 4301.988183] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 4301.988558] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4301.988732] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4301.988743] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4301.988755] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4301.988768] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4301.988786] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4301.989183] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4301.989317] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4301.989353] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 4303.992931] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[ 4304.193581] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4304.200207] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 4304.270731] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 4304.277386] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5063.229224] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5066.598001] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[ 5066.599038] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[ 5066.625081] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[ 5066.625085] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[ 5066.625087] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[ 5066.625090] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
[ 5066.625206] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5066.642842] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[ 5066.647050] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 5066.654253] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5066.660910] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5066.729004] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5066.735636] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5066.797629] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5066.804279] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5066.873339] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5066.880007] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5072.115589] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5072.122212] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5072.192216] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5072.198885] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5292.905901] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5294.566362] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[ 5294.567264] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[ 5294.591829] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[ 5294.591835] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[ 5294.591838] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[ 5294.591842] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 BGN, REV=0xB0
[ 5294.591964] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5294.609928] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[ 5294.614182] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 5294.628142] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5294.634820] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5294.703270] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5294.709942] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5294.784626] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5294.791423] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5294.870351] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5294.877029] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5296.253884] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5296.260528] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
[ 5296.331901] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[ 5296.338567] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x2-0x1
```

ping 192.168.1.1:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1325 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1514 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1518 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=1259 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=1728 ms                                                                                                                                 
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=1657 ms                                                                                                                                 
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=1481 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=1440 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=2270 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=2799 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=2624 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=2810 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=1932 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=26 ttl=64 time=1550 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=1615 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=2312 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=2218 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=31 ttl=64 time=1994 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=2736 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=2684 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=2606 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=2804 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=2333 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=8776 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=49 ttl=64 time=7446 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=51 ttl=64 time=6138 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
64 packets transmitted, 26 received, 59% packet loss, time 63230ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1259.319/2676.365/8776.722/1834.187 ms, pipe 9
```

uname -a:

```
Linux raxp-laptop 4.2.0-21-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 2 18:42:25 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question: The problem was in (big surprise) **pulseaudio** and it's network socket feature (I was experimenting with it). So, I turned it off and the problem disappears

Comment: You could describe how exactly you turned that feature off to improve your answer. Also, don't forget to accept it to mark your question as solved.